# Using Nodejs Along Side Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am about to start developing my web application in Firebase. Problem is, currently I have 100s of questions running through my head, and nothing I can find online specifically answers such.

Now from what I understand you can ONLY host assets on Firebase hosting (HTML, CSS, JS), and if you have a backend (such as Node) you will have to use a separate hosting service (like Heroku).

Firebase hosting implies that everything can be done from the browser, but I am not sure how I would get around using a backend.

For instance, if the user enters the url `http://___.com/login` I would route that in Express to `login.html`. Also if a user types in `/index` or `/home` or even nothing, it would take them to `index.html`. **How would I go about doing this without a backend?**

Another big question I have is templating. **On Node there are many templating engines, is there such a thing though when just using the frontend?**

**Would there be a way to get around those two issues above without using a backend?** I can see some benefits when using a backend such as server side rendering, and using third-party services such as Sendgrid. **But what else would I get out of using a backend such as Node?**

I guess I am just a bit confused on how a web application could be done without a backend (that you can access and control). I do not see how templating, routing, and many other things can be controlled by just the browser, and hosted within Firebase.

I plan on using Node (unless all of this is possible without a backend), and I am intending on using React and Redux as well. **Can Firebase, Node, React and Redux all be used together?**

---

I know there are a ton of questions above, but I just can not wrap my head around it all. I put all of my main question in bold, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting allows you to do single-page app style routing, you'd just add this to your `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [{"source": "**", "destination": "/index.html"}]
  }
}
```

As for templating, you'd want to look into frameworks such as React, Angular, Ember, Polymer, etc. to do dynamic content generation client-side instead of relying on server-side templates.

Firebase offers tools that can help you with the most common things you'll need when building an app (auth, database, file uploads, hosting). For these, you won't need a server at all. If and when your app needs additional custom back-end work, you can always deploy separate services that can be called by the client or even just listen to the database and trigger events directly.

And yes, you can definitely use React, Redux, and Firebase together. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your reply! First off, what exactly is `firebase.json`? Secondly, I thought React didn't do templating, or am I wrong on that? Also, React and Redux will both work without a Backend? Do you happen to know any good links on Firebase without a backend tutorial? **EDIT** I was just thinking, eventually I will need automated tasks for my web application. That would require a backend wouldn't it? If so, I could just make API calls to it, correct?

Comment: See the [Firebase Hosting guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/) for more on `firebase.json`. Yes, React and Redux will both work without a backend server. React isn't strictly a templating language but it performs the same functions as a templating language by constructing the DOM for your app.

Yes, you could make API calls to a separate backend when you need to :)

Comment: Thank you Michael! I think I have a better grasp on how some things would work.

Comment: P.S. Michael, I am sorry, but I kinda forgot to ask. I understand that the use of a server alongside Firebase is to use third-party APIs (such as Sendgrid). My question is though, do you know of any other general uses of using a server as well?

Comment: Generally you'd want to use a server to perform trusted actions that you can't figure out how to write into the client (which is inherently untrustable). This can be connecting with third-party APIs, performing data integrity operations, running firebase-queue workers, etc.

Comment: Checked Google I/O sessions about Firebase and one question related to this came to mind. Let's say I have ReactJS running on the frontend but I would like to do server side rendering for better SEO. How would I configure Firebase hosting if I had NodeJS running on Google App Engine and frontend part running on Firebase hosting.

Comment: In that case, you'd want to just use your NodeJS App Engine app to render your content and serve directly from App Engine. There isn't really a way at present for Firebase Hosting to serve any kind of dynamic content.